# Show that there is a linear rational transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Let $L$ be a circle in $\mathbb{C}$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{C}\setminus{L}$ .  It shows that there is a linear rational transformation $f$ such that $L\cup{\{a}\}$ is contained in the domain of $f$, $f (a) = b$ and $f (L) = L$.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hint: If $g(b) = \infty $ for a linear rational transformation $g$, what do you know about $g(L)?$

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3092287/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the framework of complex linear transformations (Moebius transformations) we may assume that $L$ is the real axis, and that $a$, $b\notin{\mathbb R}$. Since we want $f(\bar{\mathbb R})=\bar{\mathbb R}$ and $f(a)=b$ we also need $f(\bar a)=\bar b$. Going through the computation we find out that there are many such $f$s. Therefore we impose the additional constraint $f(\infty)=\infty$. In other words, we are looking for an $$f(z)=\lambda z+\mu$$
satisfying the given conditions. The coefficients $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are found by solving the system
$$b=\lambda a+\mu,\qquad\bar b=\lambda\bar a+\mu\ .$$
This leads to
$$\lambda={b-\bar b\over a-\bar a}\in{\mathbb R},\qquad \mu={a\bar b-\bar a b\over a-\bar a}\in{\mathbb R}\ ,$$
so that $f(\bar{\mathbb R})=\bar{\mathbb R}$ is automatically fulfilled. This proves the existence of a Moebius transformation $f$ doing the desired job.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for answering, I have two question, why can we assume that $L$ is the real axis? and what does $\mathbb{\bar{R}}$ denote?

Comment: @Yessit: All circles (and lines) are alike in this world. But you could also argue as follows: There is a certain Moebius transformation $T$ mapping the given circle $L$ to the line ${\mathbb R}$. This $T$ moves $a$ and $b$ to new points $a'$, $b'\notin{\mathbb R}$. With $a'$ and $b'$ do what I have described; then move everything back.