# Finding a homeomorphism of unit disk in complex plane that interchanges two given points and leaves all points of boundary fixed

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, conformal-geometry

I'm trying to solve problem 21 from chapter 1 of M. A. Armstrong's Basic Topology:

> Let $C$ denote the unit circle in the complex plane and $D$ the disc which it
>   bounds. Given two points $x,y \in D - C$, find a homeomorphism from D to D
>   which interchanges x and y and leaves all the points of C fixed.

I tried to find a function which interchanges two given points in the complex plane, because I know that interior of any disk is homeomorphic to the plane. Here is the details:

If $x,y$ are the points which we want to be interchanged, then define the two functions as below:
$$f:D-C \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\, \,\,\,\,\,\, st.\,\,\,\,\,\, f(z) = \frac {1}{1 -  \mid z\mid} z$$
$$g:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\, \,\,\,\,\,\, st.\,\,\,\,\,\, g(z) = f(x)+f(y)-z $$
we also have:
$$f^{-1}:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow D-C \, \,\,\,\,\,\, st.\,\,\,\,\,\, f(z) = \frac {1}{1 +  \mid z\mid} z$$
So $h=f^{-1}\circ g\circ f$ has the property in the interior of disk, but I don't know how to extend $h$ to a homeomorphism like $\hat{h}$ in order to leaving all points of $S$ fixed.

I also saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3093167/698794) and it seems to be a good argument but don't know how to extend it to the unit circle again.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: One way to do this is to constrcut a vector field supported in the open disc such that the integal curve starting at $x$ reaches $y$ in some finite time, say $t$. If $\Phi$ is the flow of this vector field then $\Phi(t)$ is a desired diffeomorphism, which is stronger than a homeomorphism. Of course, one also give a purely topological solution.

Comment: The *closed* disk is not homeomorphic to the plane. If you want to solve this problem by coming up with a homeomorphism in the plane, it should be a homeomorphism which is constant outside a compact set, or one such that $| f(z) - z|$ converges to $0$ as $|z|$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that easy. Let us first prove that your $h$ extends to $D$. To do so, we show that if $(z_n)$ is a sequence in $U = D \setminus C$ which converges to $\zeta \in C$, then $h(z_n) \to -\zeta$. Let $d = f(x)+f(y)$. An easy calculation shows that
$$h(z) = \dfrac{d-\frac{z}{1-\lvert z \rvert}}{1+\lvert d -\frac{z}{1-\lvert z \rvert} \rvert} = \dfrac{(1- \lvert z \rvert)d - z}{1-\lvert z \rvert + \lvert  (1-\lvert z \rvert)d - z\rvert} .$$

As $z_n \to \zeta$, we get $\lvert z_n  \rvert \to 1$, thus $1-\lvert z_n \rvert \to 0$ and $(1-\lvert z_n \rvert)d \to 0$ and $(1-\lvert z_n \rvert)d - z_n \to -\zeta$ and  $\lvert z_n  + (1-\lvert z_n \rvert)d \rvert \to \lvert -\zeta \rvert = 1$.  Therefore $h(z_n) \to -\zeta$.

Thus $h$ extends to a homeomorphism $H : D \to D$, but on the boundary $C$ it is the *antipodal map* which is the same as a rotation by the angle $\pi$. We have to correct this.

Let $r = \max(\lvert x \rvert, \rvert y \rvert)$. Clearly $r < 1$. Define
$$G : D \to D, G(z) = \begin{cases}  z & \lvert z \rvert \le r \\ e^{\frac{\lvert z \rvert -r}{1-r}\pi i}z & \lvert z \rvert \ge r \end{cases}$$
This map twists the annulus between $r$ and $1$. Now let
$$F = G \circ H$$
which is again a homeomorphism. Then $F(x) = H(x) = y, F(y) = H(y) = x$  and for $z \in C$ we have $F(z) = G(-z) = e^{\pi i}(-z) = z$.