# Topological homeomorphism which takes convergent sequence to a specific convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

For some reasons the sequence $x_n=1/n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is good for my porposes, and I have to deal with more general sequences (covergent ones) on $\mathbb{R}^2$. So let $y_n$ be a convergent sequence on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (let us consider $y_n\neq y_m$ if $m\neq n$). My question is: **Is there a homeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\phi(1/n,0)=y_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (or at least for $n\geq k$, for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$)?**

Comment: So, are you asking if there is a homeomorphism which takes a given convergent sequence ot another fixed convergent sequence? Or is it just that the output is only a convergent sequence (any rather than fixed). Nonetheless, I think your question is awesome. I hope you get an awesome answer to this as well.

Comment: I'm asking if in the condition where $y_n\neq y_m$ when$ m\neq n$, and $y_n$ is convergent, then is there such homeomorphism that correspond $y_n$ with the sequence ($1/n,0$). But we can ask a more general, but equivalent one: Any two convergent sequences on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that all of elements of the sequences are distinct then there is a homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that take one to another.,

Comment: I have edited your question, but one thing I can say is that continous functiosn take convergent sequence to convergent sequences. Homeomorphism corresponds convergent sequences in domain to ones in codomain I think

Comment: Proof: I do one direction, let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence with $x$ as limit in a topological space $X$. By carrying it by the continuous bijective function $f(x)$, I get another sequence $\{y_n \}$ in $Y$. I claim that $f(x)=y$ is **a** limit of the sequence $\{y_n \}$. 

Consider any open nbhd  $U$ of $y$, then the pre-image of this open nbhd $V$ is an open nbhd of $x$. We know there exists an $N$ such that for $n>N$ , $x_n \in V$, this means also that $f(x_n) \in U$.

In other words,  for any open nbhd $U$ of Y there exists an $N$ such that for $n>N$, $y_n = f(x_n) \in U$

Comment: I would suggest that you put in the abstract version of the question and maybe put the point I said as well because that may help attract interest to to this question.

Comment: I expect the answer is, yes, in first countable homogeneous spaces. In non-homogeneous space however I think counterexamples might be found

Comment: @FShrike: certainly not: the answer is no in $\mathbb{R}$. Consider $((-1)^n \frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer to write your sequence as $p_n =(x_n,y_n)$. If $p_n \to p$ **and** some $p_k = p$, it is impossible to find a homeomorphism $\phi$ such that $\phi(p_n) = (1/n,0)$ for all $n$ because $\phi(p_k) = \phi(p)  =\lim_{n \to \infty} \phi(p_n) = (0,0)$.

A positive answer to your question can be obtained if we either

1. exclude convergent sequences $(p_n)$ such that $p_k =  \lim_{n \to \infty} p_n$ for some $k$ and prove that there exists a homeomorphism $\phi$ such that $\phi(p_n) = (1/n,0)$ for all $n$
2. allow that $p_k =  \lim_{n \to \infty} p_n$ for some $k$ and prove that there exists a homeomorphism $\phi$ such that $\phi(p_n) = (1/n,0)$ for all $n \ne k$. Note that there exists at most one index $k$ such $p_k =  \lim_{n \to \infty} p_n$. This is a strong form of your "at least" variant.

We consider case 1. The proof is technically complicated.

W.l.o.g. we may assume that $p_n \to 0$ (if $p_n \to p$, then the translation $\tau(z) = z - p$ is a homeomorphism and $p_n' = \tau(p_n)$ is a sequence with this property).

We now need the following

**Lemma.** Let $R = [a,b] \times [c,d]$ be a closed rectangle. Then for any two points $p, q \in \operatorname{int} R = (a,b) \times (c,d)$ there exists a homeomorphism $h : R \to R$ keeping the boundary of $R$ fixed such that $h(p) = q$.

We do not give a proof of this intuitively clear lemma here (this would be worth another question).

We write $\lvert R \rvert = \max(b-a,d-c)$.

**Step 1.**

Since all $p_n \ne 0$ and $p_m \ne p_n$ for $m \ne n$, we can construct inductively a sequence of pairwise disjoint rectangles $R_n$ such that $p_n \in \operatorname{int} R_n$, $0 \notin R_n$ and $\lvert R_n \rvert < 1/n$.

Choose inductively boundary-fixing homeomorphisms $h_n$ on $R_n$ such that the $y$-coordinates of the $h_n(p_n)$ are pairwise disjoint and $\ne 0$. This is possible because all $[c_n,d_n]$ are infinite.

The $h_n$ and the identity on $E = (\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \setminus \bigcup_n \operatorname{int} R_n$ fit together to a homeomorphism $h$ on $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$: The map is well-defined because $h_n = id$ on $R_n \cap E$; it is clearly a bijection. It is continuous because it is continuous on all $R_n$ and on $E$ and
the $R_n$ and $E$ form a locally finite closed cover of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$. The continuity of $h^{-1}$ is verified analogously. Defining $h(0) = 0$ we get a bijection $h$ on $\mathbb R^2$. The maps $h$ and $h^{-1}$ are continuous in all points $\ne 0$. Moreover, $h$ is also continuous in $0$: Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ such that $R_n \subset U_\epsilon(0)$ for $n  \ge N$. This is possible since $p_n \in U_{\epsilon/2}(0)$ for $n \ge N_1$ and $\lvert R_n \rvert < 1/n$. Then $U = U_\epsilon(0) \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^{N-1}$ is an open neigborhood of $0$ such that $h(U) \subset U_\epsilon(0)$. The continuity of $h^{-1}$ in $0$ is verified analogously.

**Step 2.**

Using the above $h$, we can assume w.l.o.g. that the $y_n$ are  pairwise distinct and $\ne 0$.  We can now construct inductively a sequence of pairwise disjoint rectangles $R'_n$ such that $0 \notin R'_n$, $p_n =(x_n,y_n)$ and $(1/n,y_n)$  are contained in $\operatorname{int} R'_n$ and $\lvert R'_n \rvert \to 0$. The last condition can be achieved because $x_n \to 0$. Choose boundary-fixing homeomorphisms $h'_n$ on $R'_n$ such that the $h'_n(p_n) = (1/n,y_n)$. As in step 1 the $h'_n$ and the identity on  $E'' = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \bigcup_n \operatorname{int} R'_n$ fit together to a homeomorphism $h'$ on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $h'(0) = 0$.

**Step 3.**

Using the above $h'$, we can assume w.l.o.g. that $x_n = 1/n$ for all $n$. We can now construct inductively a sequence of pairwise disjoint rectangles $R''_n$ such that $0 \notin R''_n$, $p_n =(1/n,y_n)$ and $(1/n,0)$  are contained in $\operatorname{int} R''_n$ and $\lvert R''_n \rvert \to 0$. The last condition can be achieved because $y_n \to 0$. Choose boundary-fixing homeomorphisms $h''_n$ on $R''_n$ such that the $h''_n(p_n) = (1/n,0)$. As in step 1 the $h''_n$ and the identity on  $E'' = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \bigcup_n \operatorname{int} R''_n$ fit together to a homeomorphism $h''$ on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $h''(0) = 0$.

Comment: I amazed you actually solved this :O

Comment: Very very nice and genial, thanks a lot for the answer!! I would like a reference for that Lemma.

Comment: @Jacaré The Lemma is "folklore". I do not know an explict reference, but certainly it occurs somewhere in the literature. If you want, ask a new question and I shall give a proof.

Comment: @Jacaré Noting that any rectangle is homeomorphic to the closed unit disk (by a homeomorphism mapping the boundary of the rectangle onto the boundary of the unit disk) you can use https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1517052 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3674985. But a direct proof is probably easier.

Comment: @PaulFrost I asked a new question related to such lemma. Would you answer that?

Comment: Wow, what a tricky, nice proof! Very well deserved +1. BTW, the lemma follows directly from the fact that [$\mathbb{R^2}$ is strongly locally homogeneous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3938735/mathbbrn-is-a-strongly-locally-homogeneous-space), see also my comment to the new post of Jacaré.